# How to get all cryptocurrencies real-time statistics with no limit and free?

Tags: exchanges, api, live-data, statistics

How can we get almost all real-time information of cryptocurrencies (rates, transactions, live prices, blocks info, wallets, etc) for developing new cryptocurrency statistics and exchange reference (like Binance)?

We can use blockchain.com's API for BTC and LTC and some other references like chain.so, block.io etc, but what we need to get all stats for all cryptocurrencies?

I mean how Binance getting this bunch of information? and where can we get them too?

I know there is some website that sell these information and their own APIs but how they got these? and actually how can we get this bunch of information freely?

Answer (score 0):

https://blockchair.com/ is pretty good for data analysis on 9 different blockchain it allow you to filter by lots of settings like date, reward, hash, output etc... You can also directly download the data they offer in different format.

And they also have an API: https://github.com/Blockchair/Blockchair.Support/blob/master/API_DOCUMENTATION_EN.md

Comment: OK thanks, but is this reliable source? and what is it's different with coingecko.com? and it has not API for wallets for make payments?